# format for a graph function?

Tags: python, function, graph, matplotlib

here´s my function grapher program, which plots graphs:

```
import wx
import numpy
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas


class p1(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self , parent):
      wx.Panel.__init__(self , parent)

      self.minimuml = wx.StaticText(self , label = "x,min.:" , pos = (650 , 20))
      self.minimum = wx.TextCtrl(self , pos = (700 , 20) , size = (100 , -1))

      self.maximuml = wx.StaticText(self , label = "x,max.:" , pos = (650 , 60))
      self.maximum = wx.TextCtrl(self , pos = (700 , 60) , size = (100 , -1))

      self.pacel = wx.StaticText(self , label = "x,pace:" , pos = (650 , 100))
      self.pace = wx.TextCtrl(self , pos = (700 , 100) , size = (100 , -1))

      self.functionl = wx.StaticText(self , label ="f(x):" , pos = (650 , 140))
      **self.function = wx.TextCtrl(self, pos = (700 , 140) , size = (100 , -1))** 

      self.button_plot = wx.Button(self , label = "PLOT" , pos = (725 , 200))
      self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON , self.Onbutton_plot , self.button_plot)

      self.figure = matplotlib.figure.Figure()
      self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
      self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self , -1 , self.figure)

    def Onbutton_plot(self , event):

      self.minimum_Get = float(self.minimum.GetValue())
      self.maximum_Get = float(self.maximum.GetValue())
      self.pace_Get = float(self.pace.GetValue())
      **self.function_Get = int(float(self.function.GetValue()))**


      x = numpy.arange(self.minimum_Get , self.maximum_Get +       self.maximum_Get/self.maximum_Get , self.pace_Get)
      **y = self.function_Get**

      self.axes.plot(x , y)
      self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self , -1 , self.figure)



class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self , parent , title):
      wx.Frame.__init__(self , parent , title = title , size = (800 , 500))
      self.CreateStatusBar()
      filemenu = wx.Menu()
      menuExit = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT , "Exit" , "End the program")

      menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
      menuBar.Append(filemenu , "program")
      self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

      self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU , self.Exit , menuExit)


    def Exit(self , event):
      self.Close(True)



app = wx.App(redirect = False)
frame = MainFrame(None , "grapher")
p1 = p1(frame)
frame.Maximize()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

it gets the whole array for the x-values (self.minimum, maximum ....) and then amends the existing void coordinate system with a graph.

I´m searching for a fitting format for the graph for the y-variable. It want to enter the graph (p.ex. 2*x+2) into the self.function TextCtrl and read + plot it when pressing the button (def OnButton_plot). p.s. the self.function_Get variable gets the content of self.function TextCtrl. so what I need is a fitting format for this graph, similar to when I enter a number in a TextCtrl it is converted to a string and later I simply can convert it to float or integer. the difference is, that in this case I don´t have a number, but a graph function like : 2*x+2 or sin(x)

thanks in advance

Comment: Why are the first nine lines indented?

Comment: Can you give us a complete code example? And/or cut out the code that's not relevant to the issue? Put yourself in my shoes. I may know the answer to your problem but since don't know what *any* of these variables are, I'd rather not spend all day trying to guess...

Comment: I just want to type  a graph function, like 2*x+2 into a TextCtrl and then use this entering later to plot the graph. The problem is that a TextCtrl converts the entering into a string, so I need a format to which I can convert the string-function, in order to use it again, like when I enter a number into a TextCtrl I can later convert it to float or integer. the difference here is that I have a function like this: 2*x+2

Comment: Edit your question instead of commenting on your own question, it make is easier to follow.

Comment: here is my full code. Thanks in advance